# LinearLayout to right of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to place a linear layout to the right side of a frame layout.

This is the following code in my layout to set them next to each other:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.DrawingImageView
    android:id="@+id/plan_markup_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <SkiaSharp.Views.Android.SKCanvasView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/plan_markup_canvas" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/planMarkupMessage"
      android:text="Touch and drag to"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:gravity="center" />
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="250dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#888888">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, the linear layout does not appear, I believe it is being forced off the screen.

I have tried different combinations of wrap_content and match_parent for various view width/heights but things just aren't working. I have also tried putting the linear layout inside (but at the end of) the frame layout, which *worked* but it ended up cutting off the edge of the 'ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.DrawingImageView' component.

What do I need to do to get the frame layout and linear layout next to each other so that nothing overlaps or goes off the screen?

**Edit**
Here is the full layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <include
            layout="@layout/widget_toolbar" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.UIColoredSpinner
                android:id="@+id/drawing_tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plan_markup_undo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Undo" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plan_markup_continue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Continue" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.DrawingImageView
                android:id="@+id/plan_markup_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <SkiaSharp.Views.Android.SKCanvasView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/plan_markup_canvas" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/planMarkupMessage"
                    android:text="Touch and drag to"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@color/primary_light">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is my text" />
          </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        layout="@layout/widget_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.UIColoredSpinner
            android:id="@+id/drawing_tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan_markup_undo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Undo"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plan_markup_continue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Continue"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ArmgaSys.ConDoc.Droid.Views.DrawingImageView
            android:id="@+id/plan_markup_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <SkiaSharp.Views.Android.SKCanvasView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/plan_markup_canvas" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planMarkupMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Touch and drag to"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is my text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've only put the father match_parent, and I've adjusted LinearLayout child to his father with match_parent.

[EDIT] I added gravity in LinearLayout parent to end and LinearLayout child has wrap_content width.

Comment: I don't understand what you want then, this way nothing gets off the screen. Please, can you explain better what you want?

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your response. I tried out the code you suggested, but the right menu (linear layout) seems to be missing. I'll update the original question with the full layout code so you can see exactly what I'm working with. Here is an image of what the code you suggested has produced: https://ibb.co/isEuNb

Comment: I edited the layout, maybe this can help you, I think the problem is that the image is too wide and pushed the menu out of the screen.